# MissingConnectionException running CakePHP through mysql tunnel on AppFog

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, appfog

while my tunnel is connected (af tunnel) I'm trying to run a cakephp console app that would connect to my mysql database (through the tunnel).

I have this in my database config:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => '11111111ZQyI',
    'password' => '11111111111MR',
    'database' => '111111111111115bc',
    'port' => '10000',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

I would get this error message:

```
Error: exception 'MissingConnectionException' with message 
'Database connection "Mysql" is     missing, or could not be 
created.' in /.../lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php:161
Stack trace:
#0 /..../lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(262): Mysql->connect()
```

Comment: you asked a question that you answered within the same minute... `-1 on both`

Comment: why is that a -1?  I spent 15min searching for the answer.  I was doing it to save the next poor sap from wasting 15min of their time too.  I think it's important to get the correct information out on the web. that is all.

Comment: I wish I could downvote a comment, because SamuelCook I'd be down voting yours. Colin is right, it's VERY important to get the correct information out on the web, regardless of if he answered it within a minute. I've had this problem for the last 20 minutes, and this answer helped me. +1 on BOTH!

Comment: the funny thing is that stackoverflow seems to facilitate you answering your own questions.  Trust me, I'm not looking for points, this is all about getting the word out.

Comment: You did fine. it's great to have people like you who answer their own questions. +1 for you.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was that I needed to somehow invoke mysql to connect of TCP instead of sockets.  Apparently when you use localhost it automatically triggers a Socket connection and if you use 12.0.0.1 it triggers a TCP connection.  So this was the solution:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'login' => '11111111ZQyI',
    'password' => '11111111111MR',
    'database' => '111111111111115bc',
    'port' => '10000',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```